# d3.js network diagram zoom

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, diagram

I have probably a relativly simple question.

Here is my simple diagram [enter link description here](http://jsfiddle.net/yeQS2/125/)

And I would love to implement zooming in and out functionality, using the behaviour descibed here 
[enter link description here](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3681006). But I cant make it work, maybe You would spot the problem.

Thanks for Your time.

The whole zooming in functionality seems to be handled with this assignment and  function:

```
svg = d3.select("body").append("svg").attr("width", width).attr("height", height)
.call(d3.behavior.zoom().x(x).y(y).scaleExtent([1, 8]).on("zoom", zoom));

function zoom() {
svg.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);  
}
```

Comment: Refer this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yeQS2/141/)

Comment: witchcraft. thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you have tried for zooming is used for canvas. You can use transform attribute for zooming in svg.
You can put the whole graph in a  (group) element and apply transform attribute to  element.

```
svg = d3.select("body")
         .append("svg")
         .attr("width", width)
         .attr("height", height)
         .call(d3.behavior.zoom().x(x).y(y).scaleExtent([1, 8]).on("zoom", zoom))
         .append("g");

function zoom() {
    svg.attr("transform","translate("+ d3.event.translate+") scale("+d3.event.scale+")");  
}
```

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yeQS2/141/)

Comment: How it would be possible to have an opposit - zoom out as well as zoom in ? Couse in your fiddle one can only zoom out to the starting  view but not more

Comment: Because in the code, we have limited the zoom level to a minimum scale 1 and maximum scale 8 by this code 'd3.behavior.zoom().scaleExtent([1, 8])'. You can remove 'scaleExtent' to get infinite zoom in and out.

Comment: dough..missed that property.. Excuse my ignorance but is it possible to put a cap on 'zoom out' like we do on 'zoom-in' ?